# UISwitch in UITableView reset to original value while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a UITableview with custom cells in it. One of the customcell has a UISWITCH in it. When the scroll the table view the state of the switch gets reset even if I set it to ON. How can I maintain the state of the switch during scroll. Any help is appreciated.

```
-(IBAction)sameDriver:(id)sender{

if ([sender isOn]){

    NSLog(@"%@",(otherdriver.drive ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

    NSUserDefaults* defaults  = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool: YES forKey: K_SWITCH_KEY];
    [defaults synchronize];

    Switchon = [defaults boolForKey: K_SWITCH_KEY];


if(Switchon){

    otherdriver.dfname.text = fname;
    otherdriver.dlname.text = lname;
    otherdriver.demail.text = email;
    otherdriver.dpnum.text = phone;

    }
}
else if(![sender isOn]){

    NSUserDefaults* defaults  = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool: NO forKey: K_SWITCH_KEY];
    [defaults synchronize];

   NSLog(@"%@",(otherdriver.drive ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

    Switchon = [defaults boolForKey: K_SWITCH_KEY];

    otherdriver.dfname.text = drfname;
    otherdriver.dlname.text = drlname;
    otherdriver.demail.text = dremail;
    otherdriver.dpnum.text = drphone;


}}
```

i am setting the UISwitch in IB. It is inside a custom UITableviewcell.

Thanks

Comment: It'd help if you posted the code for your custom UITableViewCell class

Comment: Please see my code in the EDIT.

Comment: So there is one switch per cell?

Comment: no only one switch in one of the cell. all other cells contain only textfields.

Answer (score 3):

In your header file, declare an NSString to hold the status of the switch.
Let's name it **theSwitchPosition**.

Then, in your method which runs when the switch is triggered, make theSwitchPosition hold the status of the switch:

```
theSwitchPosition = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", switchControl.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF"];
```

After that, in the method where you create the UISwitch, set the switch's status based on the string that holds the data:

```
if ([theSwitchPosition isEqualToString:@"ON"]) {
    mySwitch.on = YES;
} else {
    mySwitch.on = NO;
}
```

This will work if you have only one UISwitch in your table view. If you have more than one, you need to use NSMutableArray instead.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're saying that if you scroll down (switch cell gets scrolled off screen), and then you scroll back up (switch cell gets scrolled back on screen) then the state of the switch isn't preserved.  Is this correct?

If so, I would guess the issue is that the cell is being recycled and recreated.  This happens when you get your cell from `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier`.  To fix this, you will need to give your special cell a different `CellIdentifier`.

If this is still unclear, please paste your code for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and I will try to help you further.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TrackerFilterCell") as! TrackerTypeFilterCellVC
        if allChecked == true {
            cell.switchButton.isOn = true
        } else {
            
            if lastIndex == 0 {
                cell.switchButton.isOn = false
            }
                
            else if rowData.id == "-1" {
                cell.switchButton.isOn = false
            }
        }
     
        return cell
        
    }